# Maven force include pakages without java classes inside it

Tags: java, maven, war

I have the next structure in my project

```
src/main/java/com/company
|
+-----controllers
|        |
|        +---->Controller1.java
|        +---->Controller2.java
|
+-----templates
|        |
|        +---->template1.tfl
|        +---->template2.tfl
|
+----->JavaClass1.java
+----->JavaClass3.java
+----->JavaClass3.java
```

I'm packagin my project in war with maven whit the next command:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
```

The problem is in the war. The folder template and the files *.tfl aren't included.

How can I force to include this files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By maven standard in the folder `src/main/java` only the java source files (*.java) will be considered. File belonging to that folder will be compiled and the generated `*.class` file will be packaged in your jar/war.
Other files have to be under the `src/main/resources` folder. They will be packaged respecting their directory tree.
So your project structure have to be:

```
src/main/
    |
    +-----java/com/company/controllers
    |        |
    |        +---->Controller1.java
    |        +---->Controller2.java
    |
    |
    +----->JavaClass1.java
    +----->JavaClass3.java
    +----->JavaClass3.java
    |
    +-----resources/com/company/templates
    |        |
    |        +---->template1.tfl
    |        +---->template2.tfl
```

Answer (score 3):

Move these files to `src/main/resources`. The `src/main/java` should only contain Java files.